# With SSDT, how do I create a column with a unique constraint?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

We have a table:

```
`CREATE TABLE dbo.Account ( 
AccountID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
AccountName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```

I'd like to add a `PartnerAccountKey` column and add a unique constraint to it (populating the data in the post-deploy scripts I assume)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Account ( 
AccountID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
AccountName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PartnerAccountKey  INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UK_Account_PartnerKey UNIQUE (PartnerAccountKey));
```

The problem is that the unique constraint is created before my post-deployment script runs, so it errors. I don't see how I can populate the data between the time the column is created and the unique constraint is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also found problems with this and after several hours of trying different approaches I came up with the two methods below.

These are workarounds and may not be ideal but hope they help.

1) Requires SQL2008 or higher.

Basically this takes advantage of the fact that CHECK CONSTRAINTS are not applied until after the post deploy script.

So I create a filtered unique index that excludes the default value and then add a check constraint to prevent the default value from being used.

However you need to select a value that you know you wont use in production.  For this example I'm assuming that I will never have a PartnerAccountKey value of zero.  However you can pick any number by creating the default in the table definition.

My publish options include "Generate smart defaults, when applicable" and "Script validation for new constraints"

I changed your table definition as below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account]
(
AccountID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
AccountName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PartnerAccountKey INT NOT NULL 
);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Account 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PartnerAccountKey CHECK (PartnerAccountKey!=0);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Acocunt_PartnerKey] 
    ON dbo.[Account] (PartnerAccountKey) WHERE PartnerAccountKey!=0;
GO
```

When the publish script runs it will

- 1) Create the column with a smart default value 0
- 2) Add the Unique Indexed view
- 3) Add the check constraint WITH NOCHECK

In your post deploy script you can then populate the correct values

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Account WHERE PartnerAccountKey=0)
BEGIN
    -- Migrate Data Here - Example

    UPDATE 
        dbo.Account 
    SET 
        PartnerAccountKey       = AccountID;
END;
```

Here are the important bits from the publish script.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account]
    ADD [PartnerAccountKey] INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [SD_Account_cb8fbf98ba884b92b63b4b2017b7de20] 
    DEFAULT 0 FOR [PartnerAccountKey];

....

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [SD_Account_cb8fbf98ba884b92b63b4b2017b7de20];

....

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Acocunt_PartnerKey]
    ON [dbo].[Account]([PartnerAccountKey] ASC) 
    WHERE PartnerAccountKey!=0;    

....

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account] WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_PartnerAccountKey] 
    CHECK (PartnerAccountKey!=0);

....

/*
    Post-Deployment Script Template                         
*/
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Account WHERE PartnerAccountKey=0)
BEGIN
    -- Migrate Data Here

    UPDATE 
        dbo.Account 
    SET 
        PartnerAccountKey       = AccountID;
END;

/*
   End - Post Deploy
*/

....

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account] 
    WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_PartnerAccountKey];
```

2) Requires SQL2012 or higher.

This method is probably cleaner however you may need to revisit the scripts at some point to clean up.

It uses a sequence to ensure the newly created column has unique values.

- 1) Create a Sequence
- 2) Use this sequence as the default value of the new column
- 3) Create unique constraint
- 4) Replace values with proper data in post-deployment script.
- 5) Optionally remove the default and sequence.

If you choose to remove the default and/or sequence then the next time you publish they will get created again.  This isn't really a problem though as the post-deploy script will simply remove them again.

First create the sequence.  I have decided to start at -1 and count backwards so I can identify that these are not the real values.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[TempSequence]
    AS INT
    START WITH -1
    INCREMENT BY -1
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO CYCLE
    CACHE 10;
```

Next the table script.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account]
(
    AccountID   INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    AccountName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PartnerAccountKey INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PartnerAccountKey] 
        DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR TempSequence),
    CONSTRAINT [UK_Account_PartnerKey] UNIQUE (PartnerAccountKey)
);
```

And the post deploy script.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Account WHERE PartnerAccountKey < 0)
BEGIN 
    -- Example - Migrate Data

    UPDATE 
        dbo.Account
    SET 
        PartnerAccountKey           = AccountID; 
END;

GO
-- Optional Remove the default 
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.default_constraints WHERE 
    name = 'DF_PartnerAccountKey' AND object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Account'))
BEGIN 
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Account DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_PartnerAccountKey];
END;
GO
-- Optional Remove the sequence 
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'TestSequence')
    BEGIN
        DROP SEQUENCE TestSequence;
    END;
GO
```

And here are the relevant parts of generated publish script.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[TempSequence]
    AS INT
    START WITH -1
    INCREMENT BY -1
    CACHE 10;

....

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account]
    ADD [PartnerAccountKey] INT CONSTRAINT [DF_PartnerAccountKey] 
    DEFAULT ( NEXT VALUE FOR TempSequence) NOT NULL;

....

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [UK_Account_PartnerKey] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    ([PartnerAccountKey] ASC);

....

/*
     Post-Deployment Script Template                            
*/
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Account WHERE PartnerAccountKey < 0)
BEGIN 
        -- Example - Migrate Data

        UPDATE 
            dbo.Account
        SET 
            PartnerAccountKey= AccountID; 
    END;

-- Optional Remove the default 
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.default_constraints WHERE 
    name = 'DF_PartnerAccountKey' AND object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Account'))
BEGIN 
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Account DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_PartnerAccountKey];
END;

-- Optional Remove the sequence 
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'TestSequence')
BEGIN
        DROP SEQUENCE TestSequence;
    END;
```

I have tested both of these method on SQL2012 Developer Edition, Visual Studio 2013 Premium and SSDT 12.0.40403.0.

Comment: I am definitely going to add this to my bag of tricks. I had not even thought about a filtered unique index as a way to get around that.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is likely to either do this in two releases - one to add the column, another to add the constraint - or put the Unique constraint in the Post-Deploy script temporarily, then add it back to the project after it's published. (or check for existence before creating it)

I found I had to do something similar when trying to create indexes with ONLINE=ON or MAXDOP options set. SSDT ignores those options when creating indexes, but I can create them in a post-deploy script that way, then move them into the main part of the project.

Comment: I appreciate this is likely the answer, but it causes other problems, b/c there are 9 other copies of the database for uat, testing and development.  We change the database often enough that I wouldn't want to oversee this two step deployment for every database every time we do something like this. I want to commit this to source control and move on.

Comment: True, but are you often adding new columns with unique constraints on them? That seems like it would be painful to maintain and scripting the population code doesn't seem fun, either. You can always leave those scripts in post-deploy portions and not add them to the DB code, though that doesn't feel right, either.

Comment: In the end, we setup custom scripts that run before deployment.  This way we we migrate the data/schema partially and then SSDT takes it from there.

Comment: As long as you remember that the compare/script generation is done against the DB before any of the scripts are run, you should be fine. I tried to manipulate an object that was giving us fits in a pre-deploy script one time and the main deployment script expected it to be unchanged and failed because it had been changed pre-deploy. Sounds like you have a workaround that works for you.

Comment: That's true.  We run the script(s) before starting up SSDT.